# Symfony 2 Gregwar captcha_code doesn't exist exception

Tags: symfony

I want to add Gregwar Bundle (captcha) to my project. I did all the steps shown here https://github.com/Gregwar/CaptchaBundle/blob/master/README.md

But, it is throwing "Variable "captcha_code" does not exist" exception. Is it smth wrong with the form theming part?

Answer (score 2):

use tag form_theme

example:

index.html.twig - template with your form, 
captcha.html.twig - template with your captcha

index.html.twig content:

```
{% form_theme form 'YourBundle::captcha.html.twig' %}     

<form action="" method="post">
...
{{ form_widget(form.captcha) }}
...
</form>
```

captcha.html.twig content:

```
{% block captcha_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
<img src="{{ captcha_code }}" alt="" title="captcha" width="{{ captcha_width }}" height="{{ captcha_height }}" />
...
{{ form_widget(form, {'attr': { 'autocapitalize': 'off','autocorrect': 'off' }}) }}
...
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Block captcha_widget has to be outside any other block, example:

```
{% block captcha_widget %}
{% set label = label|default('')|trim %}

{% if is_human %}
    -
{% else %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <div class="image">
            <img id="{{ image_id }}" src="{{ captcha_code }}" alt="" title="captcha" width="{{ captcha_width }}" height="{{ captcha_height }}" />

            {% if reload %}
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function reload_{{ image_id }}() {
                        var img = document.getElementById('{{ image_id }}');
                        img.src = '{{ captcha_code }}?n=' + (new Date()).getTime();
                    }
                </script>
                <a class="captcha_reload" onclick="reload_{{ image_id }}(); return false;" href="#">{{ 'Renew'|trans({}, 'gregwar_captcha') }}</a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>

        <div class="">{{ label }}{{ label ? '* :': ''}}{{ form_widget(form) }}</div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endif %}
```

{% endblock captcha_widget %}

{% form_theme form2 _self %}

{% block content %}
...
{% endblock %}